# Is there a command in Vimscript to get the current Operating System?

Tags: vi, vim

What the title says. I can think of some hackish ways to do it, but is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check for Windows, most scripts I have seen use the following:

```
let s:win = has("win16") || has("win32") || has("win64")
```

If none of these are defined, then it is a non-windows system and you can try the `uname` suggestion by [Martín Fixman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783224/is-there-a-command-in-vimscript-to-get-the-current-operating-system/2783260#2783260).

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure you will use Unix-like operating system, you can use

```
let os = substitute(system('uname'), "\n", "", "")
if os == "SunOS"
" Do Sun-specific stuff.
...
elseif os == "Linux"
" Do Linux-specific stuff.
...
endif
```

You can anyway use the has() command to check if some feature is supported, for more information look

```
:help has()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
has('gui_macvim') has('gui_gtk2') has('gui_gtk') has('gui_win32')
```